# Тонкие контроллеры. Куда вынести логику построения запросов и фильтрации в Laravel

Tags: laravel, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня есть приложение с REST API, в котором я хочу использовать тонкие контроллеры и вынести всю бизнес-логику в Service-классы. Однако возникла проблема с index методом, где используется ORM для построения запросов. Получаются очень большие запросы, из-за того, что приходится присоединять много других таблиц, в том числе и с агригацией. Особенно всё плохо с полиморфными сущностями. Это всё делается на уровня запроса, а не связей модели т.к. нужно сортировка на БД по присоединённым полям. В сервис это всё переносить, мне кажется не правильно, а в контроллере оставлять тем более.

Я не хочу переносить всю эту логику в модель, так как это сделает модель слишком тяжелой с учетом уже реализованных там методов фильтрации. Я ищу паттерны, которые помогут разгрузить модель и перенести логику построения запросов и фильтрации в другое место. Какие есть подходы для решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете Eloquent, то используйте его возможности. В вашем случае - это `scopes`. Для того чтобы вынести отдельные методы в отдельный класс, не нужны какие-то хитровыдуманные паттерны. Просто вынесите их в `trait` или кастомный `Query Builder`.

Вам могут посоветовать использовать так называемые `Repository` или `Queries` классы. Но никакого профита, используя `Eloquent` или `ActiveRecord`, вы от них не получите. Те же `scopes`, только названы по другому, и все усложняют. Намного легче разобраться в `scopes`, чем в этих классах "репозиториев". И уж тем более они не имеют ничего общего с паттерном репозиторий.